# Mechanize giving errors when I br.submit()

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, mechanize

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

br.set_handle_equiv(True)
#br.set_handle_gzip(True)

br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(mechanize.HTTPRedirectHandler)

br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize.HTTPRefreshProcessor(),max_time=1)

br.set_debug_http(True)
br.set_debug_redirects(True)
br.set_debug_responses(True)

br.addheaders=[('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')]#Necessary or not, depending on page

r=br.open('http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/vizier/surveys.htx')
#print r.read()
#r1=br.r()
`enter code here`#print r1.read()

#print br.title()
#print r.info()
for f in br.forms():#prints the html form-values
   print f

star=raw_input('Which source would you like to search? ')
radius=raw_input('At which search radius (in arcsec)? ')
#print br.forms
br.select_form(nr=0)
form=br.form
form['-source']=sys.argv[0]
form['-c']=star
form['-c.rs']=radius
response=br.submit() #This 'hits' the submit button
print response.read()
```

Using mechanize (et al.) I'm trying to gather data from a website when I submit this it run pretty smoothly until I look into the output and I see that an error was raised (presumably within the Javascript):

```
<EM>The following unexpected problem occured in</EM> <B>VizieR</B>:<BR>
No catalog or table matching your choices.<BR><BR>
Return to the <a href='http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR'>VizieR main Page</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class='headmsg'><span class='optncat'> having potential matches</span></div><DIV class='report'>
<H3 >Report:</H3>
<EM>If you can't find a solution, <A HREF="mailto:cds-question@unistra.fr?Subject=No%20Suitable%20Catalog%20or%20Table%20%28%40vizier.u-strasbg.fr%29&Cc=francois%40simbad.u-strasbg.fr">report to CDS</A> and insert into your message the following details:</EM><P>
```

I can't figure out what's going on, but seeing as though I'm pretty new to all of this I probably wouldn't stand a chance to anyway. Hoping someone can point at my errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Would you post the source code of the site you are trying to log into ?

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/bodieskate/5882227) ya go. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I can't see the gist, it's somehow lost, maybe expired ?

Comment: Yeah, the site is acting funny (just tried again). I'll try again, but in the meantime here's the site url http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/ thanks again.